# Django Inherited Field Access

Tags: django

As of the most current version, Django does not allow a subclass to have a variable with the same name as a variable in its superclass, if that variable is a Field instance.

I need a subclass to modify this variable, which I call 'department'.  Calling my classes super and sub, I need sub to modify the department variable it inherits from super.  If I redeclare it, Django throws a field error.  Of course, if I don't, department is not in scope for reassignment.  If super has no department I get database errors.  I get weird behaviour when I try rewriting **init**:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(theSuperClass, self).__init__()
```

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `super` must be the **current** class (ie the subclass), not the superclass.

Also, you should pass on the arguments passed to `__init__`. So it should be:

```
class MySubClass(MySuperClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```